# St. Athanasius on Papacy?

Tags: reference-request, papacy, athanasius

What did [St. Athanasius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasius_of_Alexandria) believe about the [Papacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope) and are there any special mentions of the *bishop of Rome* in his writings?

Comment: What specifically are you asking about regarding St. Athanasius' beliefs about the papacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

St. Robert Bellarmine, [*On the Roman Pontiff*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5349) bk. 1 ch. 10 "A Third Question is Proposed, and the Monarchy of Peter is Proved from the Citation of the Gospel According to Matthew 16":

> St. Athanasius wrote both in his name and in that of the Synod of Alexandria: “You are Peter, and upon your foundation the pillars of the Church, that is the bishops, are strengthened.” Athanasius elegantly makes Peter the foundation, upon which the Bishops rest and upon which as pillars, the whole building has been placed.

Comment: In which specific writings does Athanasius make these statements?

Comment: Paul also claims to have laid a foundation that others build upon.  "You are Peter, and upon **your foundation** the pillars of the Church, that is the bishops, are strengthened."  Perhaps the "your foundation" is the gospel of Christ and not a man.